# Why the data printed in console be different form preview? and the data changed in chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, data-structures, frontend, console.log

here is my source data in preview
[source data in preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0XDPn.png)

and my console print:
[console print](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ioTLy.png)

and how it prints
[how it prints: [code]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZkxPX.png)

***Problem***

as we can see, in console, and when render, the 'gender' changes from **integer** 1 or **integer** 2 to **string** '男' or '女',

the source data type in database is **small integer**.

I wonder how it becomes that( and why it becomes what the really gender means.

When I render the data in a table, the first render is 1, but **the next time** it becomes '男'

***Sol***

And my way to solve is that I use **JSON to stringify and parse the data**.
it can solve the problem temporarily.
[how I solve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rz5Tp.png)

***Still Got Problem***

But somehow I click the button of the table, the table data - genders all become '男' or '女' while the gender should be 1 or 2.

I wonder what is going on. Thanks!

Comment: Share your code, please.

Comment: The replacement of integer 1/2 to 男/女 doesn't happen by default or magic. It is done somewhere in your code, or code that you rely on. It is impossible for us to have any idea about what is going on without seeing that code.

Comment: @visibleman @ Yashwardhan Pauranik, I just print response right after the request, my code is in pic3